# Программа "Блок схема" java eclipse. Помогите исправить программу

Tags: java, eclipse

Как сделать, чтобы после ответа "нет" на вопрос  "оно двигается", был переход на
if(Answer("А должно? : ")) {   (это самый последний вопрос), вместо "заклей скотчем" и "конец", но чтобы всё остальное работало.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {

```
    static void Header() {
        System.out.println("Программа выявления проблем");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
    static boolean Answer(String caption){
        System.out.print(caption);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op = sc.next();
        if (op.equals("да")) return true;
        if (op.equals("нет")) return false;

        System.out.print("Неверный ввод. \nПрограмма  завершила работу.");
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    }
    static boolean Answer1(String caption){
        System.out.print(caption);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op = sc.next();
        if (op.equals("да")) return false;
        if (op.equals("нет")) return true;

        System.out.print("Неверный ввод. \nПрограмма  завершила работу.");
        System.exit(0);
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Header();

    
   if  (Answer1("Оно двигается? : "))
       System.out.print(""); 
   
   else if(Answer("А должно? : ")) {
      System.out.println("Нет проблем!");
            System.out.println("Конец");
            System.exit(0);
   }      
  
            System.out.println("Заклей скотчем!");
            System.out.println("Конец");
            System.exit(0);
    if(Answer("А должно? : ")) {
        System.out.println("Cмажь маслом!");
        System.out.println("Конец!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
        System.out.println("Нет проблем!");
    System.out.println("Конец");


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведите в порядок оформление кода, у вас получился эталонный пример, как не нужно делать, и из-за этого путаница.

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вам нужно что то наподобие следующей конструкции:

```
    if ("Это двигается?") { // yes
        if ("Это должно двигаться?") { // yes
            System.out.println("Все ОК!");
        } else { // no
            System.out.println("Используй клей!");
        }

    } else { // no
        if ("Это должно двигаться?") { // yes
            System.out.println("Используй масло!");
        } else { // no
            System.out.println("Все ОК!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто сделать - привести в соответствие условия и ответы. Это означает, что нужно посмотреть, что возвращает функция Answer1() если ввести "нет" и потом посмотреть, что происходить в программе после этого.